Server files not showing up in workspace
This is currently what my file workspace looks like. it shows my computer files, but not my schools server files. I need access to them to properly submit homework! I don't know how to make my terminal files appear. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. 
This is wat it's supposed to look like. (C++)
